# Number of sets such that $A+B+C<10$

Tags: combinatorics

How many sets of $A,B,C$ are there such that they are all non-negative integers and $A+B+C<10$.

Answer: I tried taking it that $A+B+C+D=10$. Then, its like we have $10$ balls and $4$ bins, which implies we have $^{10}C_4$ such sets. Does this make sense, as I don't seem to have account for the non-negative part and don't know how to?

Comment: If you want sum **less** than $10$, you want sum $\le 9$. Introduce the extra variable, want sum of $4$ equal to $9$, number of solutions is $\binom{12}{3}$ by Stars and Bars.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. However, when we add the extra variable dont we want that $A+B+C+D = 10$, which implies we want a sum of 10? I'm slightly confused as to why we still want sum $<=9$.

Comment: @Jojo: $A+B+C+D=10$ could be satisfied as $4+0+6+0$, which doesn't meet the condition because $A+B+C=10$ there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introducing $D$ is the right way to go, but from there you should treat it as a [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, yielding $\binom{9+3}{3}$ different solutions. Namely, you have 9 balls (the sum must be *less than* 10, as pointed out by drhab) and 3 bin dividers that must be arranged in some sequence.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering how would the problem be solved if we wanted number of sets for $A+ B + C>10$?

Comment: @Jojo: Then there are infinitely many, of course.

Comment: Also, my reasoning behind adding $D$ was so that we could have $A+B+C+D = 10$, but why do we add $D$ and still want the sum to be less than less than 10?

Comment: @Jojo: $D$ can be $0$, like the other numbers can.,